# ReactJS - onClick SweetAlert is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, sweetalert

I'm using ReactJS (and nodejs, mongodb..) and I have projects with the delete option and I want to show a delete alert confirm window and I'm using SweetAlert for the first time. It shows the SweetAlert but doesn't let me choose the option, delete the project immediately. I'll show a gif so you can see what is happening.

Thank you!

**My ProjectPage Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import moment from 'moment';

import SweetAlert  from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert'
import Tasks from '../../TaskList/Tasks/Tasks';

import './ProjectPage.css';



class ProjectPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            project: {},
            alert: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const { match: { params } } = this.props;

        fetch(`/dashboard/project/${params.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            }).then(project => {
                this.setState({
                    project: project
                })
            })
    }

deleteProject(e){
    const getAlert = () => (
        <SweetAlert
        warning
        showCancel
        confirmBtnText="Yes!"
        confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
        cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
        title="Are you sure you want to delete this project?"
        onConfirm={() => this.deleteFile()}
        onCancel={() => this.onCancelDelete()}
        >
        You will not be able to recover this project!
    </SweetAlert>
    );
    this.setState({
        alert: getAlert()
    });

    e.preventDefault();
}

onCancelDelete(){
    this.setState({
        alert: null
    });
}

    render() {

        const { match: { params } } = this.props;

        const BackgroundImage = {
            backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.project.imageURL})`,
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            height: '350px',
            opacity: '0.7'
        }
        return (

     <div>
         <header style={BackgroundImage}>
 [...]
               <form method='POST' action={`/dashboard/project/${params.id}/delete?_method=DELETE`}>

                   <button id='button__project-delete' style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }} className='button__options--project btn btn-outline-secondary' 
       type='submit' onClick={() => this.deleteProject()}>Delete</button> {this.state.alert}

               </form>

         </header>
  [...]
     </div>

            );
    }
}
export default ProjectPage;
```

**GIF what's happening:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks your page refreshed on button click, because it is inside a form object. On button click, click event can not be accessible. So `e.preventDefault()` does not work.

You have to pass event object to **deleteProject()** method.
Change this line

```
<button id='button__project-delete' style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }} className='button__options--project btn btn-outline-secondary' 
   type='submit' onClick={() => this.deleteProject()}>Delete</button> {this.state.alert}
```

to

```
<button id='button__project-delete' style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }} className='button__options--project btn btn-outline-secondary' 
   type='submit' onClick={(e) => this.deleteProject(e)}>Delete</button> {this.state.alert}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState({
  alert: getAlert()
});
```

Please check after changing this to

```
this.setState({
  alert: getAlert
});
```